# (R) Bin a numeric column to count occurrences after group by

Tags: r, dataframe, binning

Apologies if the title of the post is a bit confusing. Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame("chr" = rep("chr1",30), "position" = sample(c(1:50), 30, replace = F) , 
         "info" = sample(c("X","Y"), 30, replace = T), 
         "condition"= sample(c("soft","stiff"), 30, replace = T) )

## head(test)
   chr position info condition
1 chr1       31    Y      soft
2 chr1       15    Y      soft
3 chr1       14    X      soft
4 chr1        3    X      soft
5 chr1       42    X     stiff
6 chr1       43    X     stiff
```

I want to bin the `position` column. Let's say with a size of 10. Then based on the condition (either soft or stiff), I would like to count the occurrences in the `info` column. So the data would look something like this (not the actual result from the data above)

```
   chr start end condition count_Y count_X
1 chr1   1    10    soft      2       3
2 chr1   1    10    stiff     0       2
3 chr1   11   20    soft      2       5
4 chr1   11   20    soft      1       2
5 chr1   21   30    soft      2       0
6 chr1   21   30    stiff     0       4
```

To make it easier, it is probably better to create two data frames based on condition and then apply the binning and counting, but I am stuck on this part. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match your sample input. it would be nice for testing to make sure those match up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut` or even easier using integer division `%/%` for the binning (Thx to @MrFlick for the hint), `dplyr::count` and `tidyr::pivot_wider` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)

test |>
  mutate(
    bin = position %/% 10 + 1,
    start = (bin - 1) * 10 + 1,
    end = bin * 10
  ) |>
  count(chr, start, end, condition, info) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = info, 
    values_from = n, 
    names_prefix = "count_",
    values_fill = 0
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   chr   start   end condition count_X count_Y
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <int>   <int>
#> 1 chr1      1    10 soft            4       0
#> 2 chr1      1    10 stiff           2       1
#> 3 chr1     11    20 soft            3       3
#> 4 chr1     21    30 soft            1       1
#> 5 chr1     21    30 stiff           3       1
#> 6 chr1     31    40 soft            0       2
#> 7 chr1     31    40 stiff           2       1
#> 8 chr1     41    50 soft            0       1
#> 9 chr1     41    50 stiff           4       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please check the below code `base r` approach

```r
# Bin the "position" column with a bin size of 10
test$position_bin <- cut(test$position, breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 10), include.lowest = TRUE)

# Count occurrences in the "info" column based on the "condition"
count_result <- table(test$position_bin, test$condition, test$info) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c('position_bin','condition','info','Freq')) %>% 
  reshape(idvar = c('position_bin','condition'), timevar = 'info', v.names = 'Freq', direction = 'wide')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   position_bin condition Freq.X Freq.Y
1        [0,10]      soft      4      0
2       (10,20]      soft      3      3
3       (20,30]      soft      1      1
4       (30,40]      soft      0      2
5       (40,50]      soft      0      1
6        [0,10]     stiff      2      1
7       (10,20]     stiff      0      0
8       (20,30]     stiff      3      1
9       (30,40]     stiff      2      1
10      (40,50]     stiff      4      1
```